# fade in div following showDiv() setTimeout

Tags: jquery, css, settimeout, fadein

Really quick question - (I hope!)

I have a div that doesnt display until the rest of the page has loaded using:

```
<script>
    function showDiv(){
        var obj = document.getElementById('test');
        obj.style.display = 'block';
    }
</script>
```

in the head of my html, and the following code in the body:

```
<body onLoad="setTimeout('setTimeout(showDiv()', 1000);">
<div id="test" style="display:none;">
```

While the div loads after a set time correctly, I was wondering if there was a way to fade this div in after the given "Timeout", using something like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){  // $(document).ready shorthand
$('#test').hide().fadeIn(1500);
});
</script>
```

for example? At the moment, the div suddenly appears, although I am hoping to get it to fade in somehow. I have tried to merge these two js functions, but to this end unsuccessfully. Any help or advice much appreciated!

Comment: `setTimeout('setTimeout(showDiv()', 1000);`is not valid syntax.

Comment: you have an error in your body onload event setTimeout('setTimeout(showDiv()', 1000); one parenthi is missing

Comment: your body onload should be: setTimeout(showDiv(), 1000);

Comment: @Juddling you don't need the parenthesis after showDiv, otherwise the browser will run the function right there.

Comment: @Dennis do you mean it would execute showDiv before the timeout?

Comment: `setTimeout(showDiv(), 1000);` would run showDiv() and provide its return value as the argument to setTimeout. `setTimeout(showDiv, 1000);` would provide the showDiv function as an argument to setTimeout.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

```
$(function(){

    $('#test').hide();

    setTimeout(function(){
        $('#test').fadeIn('slow');
    },1000);

});
```

Answer (score 7):

`$('#test').hide().delay(1500).fadeIn('slow');`

## [JsFiddle DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/uJpqJ/1/)

[jQuery's .delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/)

Answer (score 0):

You should use the load event in jquery, like so:

```
$(window).load(function() {
  $('#test').fadeIn('slow');
});
```

See: http://api.jquery.com/load-event/

`<body onLoad="setTimeout('setTimeout(showDiv()', 1000);">`is not cool in jquery land. :p

See also: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: thanks for all the responses - I know how messy and poor my code is and can only apologise!!! I used AlienWebguys function which worked like a charm. Thanks again